# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource (Reason: CORS request not http) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm currently making a fighting game overlay, so security isn't an issue as it's a local file that only I can access.

The problem I've been encountering is the one listed in the title, I can't seem to find any ways of solving it after searching around.

Here's the Javascript:

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //AJAX data request sent to server(in this case server being local json file)
var streamJSON = '../sc/streamcontrol.json'; //specifies path for streamcontrol output json
var scObj; //variable to hold data extracted from parsed json
var startup = true; //flag for if looping functions are on their first pass or not
var animated = false; //flag for if scoreboard animation has run or not
var cBust = 0; //variable to hold cache busting value

xhr.overrideMimeType('application/json'); //explicitly declares that json should always be processed as a json filetype

function pollJSON() {
    xhr.open('GET',streamJSON+'?v='+cBust,true);
    xhr.send();
    cBust++;
}

pollJSON();
setInterval(function(){pollJSON();},500);

xhr.onreadystatechange = parseJSON;

function parseJSON() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        scObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        if(animated == true) {
            scoreboard();
        }
    }
}

function scoreboard() {
    var game = scObj['game'];
    var round = scObj['round'];

    if(startup == true) {
        $('#game').html(game);
        $('#round').html(round);
    }
}

setTimeout(scoreboard,300);

}
```

Here's the JSON code:

```
{
"cTitle1": "",
"cTitle2": "",
"game": "SSBM",
"mText1": "",
"mText2": "",
"mText3": "",
"mText4": "",
"p1Name": "gamer",
"p1Score": "0",
"p1Team": "",
"p2Name": "gaming",
"p2Score": "0",
"p2Team": "",
"round": "Winner's Finals",
"timestamp": "1574024799"
}
```

And the HTML code:

````
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
    <head>  
        <script src="../js/read.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/greensock-js/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/playercam.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="all">
            <div id="main">
                <div id="divContent">
                    <div id="rdWrapper">
                        <span id="game">SSBM</span>
                        <span id="round">Round</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="divBot">
                    Stream by MegabyteMelee
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var rdSize = '160px'; //default font size of round container, should match 'font-size' value of #round
        </script>
    </body>
</html>```

Any sort of help is appreciated!
````

Comment: I do suggest you reading up on CORS on MDN. Basically, you need to set up the server to provide a header saying that only sites with a particular URL may use its API. Modern browsers has this limitation to protect browser users from XSS attack.

Comment: Do you control the server? How are you hosting it locally?